# Why are float numbers not being classed as a valid input in this python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if use == '1':
    n1 = input("Enter first number:              ")
    if n1.isdigit() or n1 == float:
        print("" + n1)
        m = input("Enter method (+ - / *):          ")
    else:
        print("That is not a valid number!")
```

This code lets integers pass through and outputs the message if the input is not a number, but it doesn't let float numbers through. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
if n1.replace('.','').replace('-','').isdigit():
```

or

```
def isfloat(value):
  try:
    float(value)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    return False
```

Comment: how would i change the first way of doing it so that it can also look for a negative float?

Comment: Think about why the given solution works for decimals, and then you can apply that to negative numbers.

Comment: I have done that, I need it to be able to know if the input is a negative decimal

Comment: how would i change the first way of doing it so that it can also look for a negative float? @Adem Öztaş

Answer (score 0):

you can not check the type of object with `n1 == float` you can use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)

```
isinstance(n1,float)
```

also As the result of `input` in python 3 is a `string` , you need to convert `n1` to a proper format for check , like `float(n1)` and check , but in this case i suggest change your `if` to :

```
  try:
    if if n1.isdigit() or float(n1) :
        print("" + n1)
        m = input("Enter method (+ - / *):          ")
  except ValueErorr:
        print("That is not a valid number!")
```

Comment: Still says it's an invalid number

Comment: @Kasra `input` returns only `string`

Comment: @AdemÖztaş ,No, if it wasn't a digit that raise a `ValueErorr` that i refine that by adiing a `try` !

Comment: @Kasra Python 2.x returns NameError, Python 3.x returns ValueError

Comment: Yep ! and the OP is using 3.x !